# Xamarin component creation & reusability

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am learning Xamarin and wanting to display the following in a page:

| Time Period | DEALS | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SalesTeam | sum | sum |
| SalesRegion | sum | sum |
| SalesRegion | sum | sum |
| SalesRegion | sum | sum |
| SalesRegion | sum | sum |

..

..

..

..

| TOTALS |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HOUSE TOTAL | sum | sum |
| F2F TOTAL | sum | sum |
| ZOOM TOTAL | sum | sum |

So one header at the top where the Time Period will be bound to a property, two static headers DEALS & AMOUNT.
There are 3 SalesTeams in the results and the values in this row will be the sum of the SalesRegion results for each team that I will bind to, so I would have 3 * SalesTeam & Region "tables" then the Totals "table".

These all are formatted the same so I get the feeling there must be a way of "templating" each "row" for adding dynamically rather than copy & pasting the grid layout and then if new sales team is brought in copy and paste again? Is there a correct way for me to create this layout and also it be useable in a few different pages in my Xamarin mobil app?

Comment: use a ContentView

Comment: Cheers Jason, would I create a contentView for each row or???

Comment: That would defeat the entire purpose of your question.  Create a ContentView that represents the UI for the row, and then reuse it.  Or use a Grouped ListView or CollectionView

Comment: Can you try this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-datagrid/